# First instance image on canvas disappears when second instance is created

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I've created a method on a class that creates instances of the class resistor, and when a resistor is created, and image will appear on the tkinter canvas. Theres also a method that allows the image to be moved, so what happens is that when I create the first instance, I move the image, and then create the second instance, but when I do this, the first image disappears, but I believe that what happens is that is moves exactly where the second image is, but I don't know why this happens. Here's the code:

```
class SideBar():
    def createResistor(self, value, name):       # Method used to create instance of class Resistor
        Res1 = Resistor(self.root, value, name)
        self.resList.append(Res1)

class Resistor():
    def cargarimg(self, archivo): # Se carga imagen
        ruta = os.path.join('img', archivo)
        imagen = PhotoImage(file = ruta)
        return imagen

    def show_res(self):
        resImage = self.cargarimg('Res.png')
        MA.MP.paintWindow.image = resImage
        MA.MP.paintWindow.create_image(100, 100, image = resImage)

    def move(self, e):   # Method that allows image to be moved
        resImage = self.cargarimg('Res.png')
        MA.MP.paintWindow.image = resImage
        MA.MP.paintWindow.create_image(e.x, e.y, image = resImage)    
    
    def __init__(self, root, resistance, name):
        self.root = root
        self.resistance = resistance
        self.name = name
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 50
        self.show_res()
        MA.MP.paintWindow.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move)
```

**Update** I've done tests by making a the coordinates x and y parameters, but the first image still disappears, this makes me believe that either for some reason the first image was deleted or it is replaced by the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is by using an lru_cache on the loading method.

```
from functools import lru_cache

class Resistor():
    @lru_cache(None)
    def cargarimg(self, archivo): # Se carga imagen
        ruta = os.path.join('img', archivo)
        imagen = PhotoImage(file = ruta)
        return imagen
```

This replaces the image reference saving, so you can remove this line from all your methods.

```
    MA.MP.paintWindow.image = resImage
```

Comment: What is the another way to solve this? It did solve the problem of the image disappearing, but remember the method to make the image move? Well, now whenever I move an image it leaves a trace.

Comment: @igmochang that's a completely unrelated error. You need to use the canvas.move method instead of recreating the image in a new place.